# Mocking an Eloquent Model

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I've looked through literally hundreds of pages, and I can't seem to find what makes my situation different than the working examples I've found on these pages.

I'm using Laravel 4.2, PHPUnit 4.3.1, and latest Mockery from Composer. I'm running a PHPUnit test on my Controller, AppController, and I'd like to intercept an Eloquent database save() by mocking the model. While there are no errors thrown when I create the Mock, the mock also isn't attaching to my model, so the rows are still being created.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

My error from Mockery: `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method save() from Mockery_0_EventRsvp should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

```
// Located at /app/tests/app/AppControllerTest.php
class AppControllerTest extends TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        Session::start();
        Mail::pretend();
    }
    public function tearDown() {
        parent::tearDown();
        \Mockery::close();
    } 
    public function testPostApp() {
        $myvar = array();
        $this->mock = \Mockery::mock('Eloquent','EventRsvp');
        $this->app->instance('EventRsvp', $this->mock);
        $this->mock
                ->shouldReceive('save')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn('true');
        $response = $this->call('POST', '/3tDYSL0', $myvar);
    }
}
```

---

```
// Located at /app/controllers/AppController
class AppController extends BaseController {
    public function saveApp($shortUrl){
        $rsvp = new EventRsvp;
        $rsvp->fieldone = '124';
        $rsvp->fieldtwo = '30233';
        $rsvp->save();

        $returnredirect = Redirect::to(Request::path(). '/complete');
        return $returnredirect;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Located at /app/models/EventRsvp.php
<?
class EventRsvp extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('id');
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function relationshipone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('RelationshipOne','idone');
    }

    public function relationshiptwo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('RelationshipTwo','idtwo');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is example of non testable one. Read about dependency injection, and why it is 'bad' to use `new Class` in your controller. You can't refer to that `new Class` by mocking, you need to inject mock to your controller.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Hmm, after reading, yep, you're right. My entire codebase is written this way, looks like I have a big task in front of me. Can you make your comment a answer? Looks good enough to mark as the answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead of calling `new EventRsvp`.

You may want to create a repository that will provide `EventRsvp`s to your controller, then you can easily mock the repo and inject it instead of the real one.

Just so you know, while it is feasible to achieve what you tried, I wouldn't do that:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('overload:EventRsvp');
$mock->shouldReceive('save')->once()->andReturn(true);

$response = $this->call('POST', '/3tDYSL0', $myvar);
```

This is **instance mocking** with Mockery, and it will catch `new EventRsvp` call in your controller, and use that `$mock` instead of real model. But again, use dependency injection, it is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for providing the workaround - it'll take awhile to convert my whole codebase to use the DI, so I'll have to use the workaround while I do that. However, when I use the `overload` as you displayed, I get this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function mockery_getExpectations() on a non-object`. No one else on Google seems to have that issue...any idea?

Comment: Ok - added the path, so now its `Mockery::mock('overload:app\models\EventRsvp');` and that runs with no `mockery_getExpectations()` errors or my original errors! However, the EventRsvp row is still being created. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Looks like adding the `overload:` doesn't respect the `once()` call and that is why there isn't the original exception anymore. If I change the mock to something that doesn't exist, like `Mockery::mock('overload:adsfadsf');` the test still runs successfully with no errors, even though that method is never called in the controller.

Comment: No, it respects `once` like usually. However if you by any chance inject `EventRsvp` or instantate it somewhere else, then it may cause problem. So make sure you don't inject it in the constructor, **or better use DI now**

Comment: Ahhh, that was it, I was injecting it in the constructor - a mixture of all my testing. Works correctly now. Thanks for showing the right way, DI, and a temporary workaround!